# jQuery: Is there some generic global event fired on AJAX start and complete that can be listened to?

Tags: jquery, ajax, events, user-interface

Essentially, I'd like to create interface elements that act or change any time any AJAX request is made in the application (loaders, etc.).

I feel like I'm overlooking something, but I can't seem to find a way to listen for such an event globally and act on it.

If there isn't, is there a way to hook such an event into jQuery to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) methods. And here's a list of all [global ajax event handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) at your disposal.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/ you should be able to do just about anything inside that handler before every AJAX request is fired.